# WebRTC: Have multiple tracks (or streams) and identify them on the other side

Tags: webrtc

I'm using WebRTC to build a Skype-like application. I want one party to be able to send a feed from their webcam, while sharing their screen at the same time.

On the receiving end, however, I can't find any way to identify what type of stream I'm receiving -- label and ID are reset to a new value (bummer, I was hoping to identify it by its source ID), and I can't find any options for adding my own metadata to the streams or tracks. How does the receiving client know what type of media I'm sending them?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, MediaStreamTracks get a new ID assigned on the other side. MediaStreams however, keep their assigned IDs, so use those when doing AddTrack, and then use a DataChannel to send information about the stream based on its ID.

Comment: this unfortunately a hacky solution but I don't see how else it could be done.when receiving multiple tracks you are not certain you will get all infos in the correct order even if it's the same stream.Any workarounds on that?